# Restrict Dates and/or Times for Datetime Pickers

Tags: html, node.js, mongoose, datetimepicker, express-handlebars

I'm make a website that require me to be able to restrict the dates and/or times that can be picked, before saving the date into a database. I've been using `<input type='datetime-local'>`, but I have no clue on how to prevent certain dates or times from being chosen. Is there a way I can prevent users from choosing a certain date and/or time using the tools in html/handlebars or express/express-handlebars, and work with mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `js-datepicker` https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-datepicker

**Date**

To disable dates use

```
const picker = datepicker('.some-input', {
  disabledDates: [
    new Date(2099, 0, 5),
    new Date(2099, 0, 6),
    new Date(2099, 0, 7),
  ]
})
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-datepicker#disableddates

To disable more complex date, use `disabler`

```
const picker1 = datepicker('.some-input1', {
  // Disable every Tuesday on the calendar (for any given month).
  disabler: date => date.getDay() === 2
})
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-datepicker#disabler

**Time**

This does not seem to cover Time selection,

You can use a separate library for that like https://www.npmjs.com/package/timepicker and use `disableTimeRanges` or search other libraries that may include both date and time selection in the same script